# euca-import-volume conversion stuck on pending

Tags: eucalyptus

I'm following imaging guide docs to create an EBS backed image:  https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#image-guide/img_task_install_hvm_image.html

```
#import to volume
euca-import-volume CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-1901.raw --format raw --availability-zone zone-1 --bucket imagebucket --description "ebs backed centos7"
```

The conversion task after import is stuck in `Pending conversion` at `ApproximateBytesConverted 0` and is making no progress.  Any ideas on common causes of this?

```
[root@desktop ~]# euca-describe-conversion-tasks
TaskType    IMPORTVOLUME    TaskId  import-vol-a6baf98c ExpirationTime  Wed Apr 17 09:25:47 EDT 2019    Status  active  StatusMessage   Pending conversion
DISKIMAGE   DiskImageFormat RAW DiskImageSize   8589934592  VolumeId    vol-4ddda573    VolumeSize  8   AvailabilityZone    zone-1  ApproximateBytesConverted   0
```

The imaging worker is configured with m2.2xlarge but I'm seeing conflicting info about whether its launching.

```
[root@cloud ~]# euca-describe-instances --filter tag-value=euca-internal-imaging-workers
[root@cloud ~]# esi-describe-images
    SERVICE     VERSION  ACTIVE     IMAGE      INSTANCES 
    imaging     4.4.101    *     emi-ebfa1114      1     
 loadbalancing  4.4.101    *     emi-ebfa1114      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion task staying in the pending state means there is an issue
with the imaging worker instance.

The reason you do not see output from `euca-describe-instances` is that
the imaging worker runs in the `(eucalyptus)imaging` service account
rather than the `eucalyptus` account. To see the instance details:

```
#
# euare-rolelistbypath --as-account '(eucalyptus)imaging'
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/internal/imaging/euca-internal-imaging-service-Role-XXXXXXXXXXXXX
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/imaging/ImagingServiceAdministrator
# 
#
# eval $(euare-assumerole arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/imaging/ImagingServiceAdministrator)
# 
#
# euca-describe-instances
RESERVATION r-3170...
# 
#
# eval $(euare-releaserole)
#
#
```

If there are issues with launching the instance then the CloudFormation
service may have useful details, e.g.:

```
# euform-describe-stacks
# euform-describe-stack-events
```

The most common issue with the imaging worker is forgetting to set the ntp
server to use, e.g.:

```
# euctl services.imaging.worker.ntp_server=time.google.com
```

this is just an example, you should use the ntp server for your environment.

To allow you to SSH to the imaging worker instance and check logs you 
should use `euca-import-keypair` as the imaging service administrator and
then configure the key name:

```
# euctl services.imaging.worker.keyname=KEYNAMEHERE
```

An easy way to restart the imaging worker and pick up any configuration changes is:

```
# euctl services.imaging.worker.configured=false
# # wait for shutdown ...
# euctl services.imaging.worker.configured=true
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The time was off on the euca image worker.  euctl services.imaging.worker.ntp_server=[your time server] did the trick.  Thanks, Steve.

Comment: It may be useful to include this setting in the runtime config instructions for the imaging worker.  A search of the docs shows its only mentioned in an unrelated index of environment options yet accurate time settings seems to be a requirement for a properly running imaging worker instance.

Comment: I've opened a documentation issue to include the imaging worker ntp server setting https://github.com/Corymbia/documentation/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the manual helper instance method to create EBS backed hvm images: https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#image-guide/img_task_install_hvm_image.html

Option C: Install an EBS image using a helper instance

It *is* technically a supported method so I don't feel like its a workaround but it would be convenient to understand why Option A (euca-import-volume) isn't working for me as described.